# On Attrition repair-inspection

Tags: phrase-meaning

"perform repair , on attrition only"

Comment: Give more details.

Comment: It's an unusual (*very* "domain-specific") usage. Normally, **attrition** means *the process of **reducing the strength or effectiveness** of someone or something through sustained attack or pressure*. but in this exact context, it means ***reduce the deleterious effect*** of a fault, rather than completely repair something. That's to say they're not gonna attempt to restore the failing component (in a vehicle, washing machine, or whatever) back to "as new" condition - they're just gonna make it "functional" - effectively, a "stop-gap" repair until the entire machine is scrapped.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22on+attrition+only+.+Reduce+Staffing%22) *The reforecast of the station staffing reductions will be **based on attrition only***, which again has a slightly different meaning. What they mean there is they're not planning to *sack* anyone - they intend to reduce staffing levels simply by ***not replacing*** workers as they retire, or resign voluntarily for personal reasons. That's a far more common "non-literal" use of ***attrition***.

Comment: ...and [here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22because+of+the+policy+during+sea%22) *Because of the policy during SEA hostilities to procure mainly for combat and **operational attrition only**, our modification and service life extension programs have had to accept the burden of modernizing our older aircraft...*, where ***attrition*** refers to only buying new warplanes to replace those that have simply become worn out or damaged beyond repair (they won't buy more planes to *increase* the size of the fleet).

Comment: I suspect it means make repairs  only to assemblies showing  normal "wear and tear", i.e. replace items if there is breakage.  **attrition** can refer to something becoming worn down.

Comment: Who says this is a machine? Could be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Damage, degradation. What this sentence says is that if the machine has suffered any degradation of the material (e.g. rust, or 'wear and tear' over time, chafing), only then perform a repair.
This remark seems a little redunant though, because if everything's in good condition, there's nothing to repair in the first place.